# concating string with comma to join a long string

Tags: c#, generics

I am getting a List of below class.

```
 public class SmsResponse
    {
        public string AliasName { get; set; }
        public string CellPhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public int Response { get; set; }
    }
```

I am passing this list to a function to check if the response field has response other than 0 , if it have than it is a error for which i have to prepare a status string by this method `PrepareStatusString();`.

```
bool isSuccess = EvaluateSmsResponse(responseList);  //list of smsresponse class

private bool EvaluateSmsResponse(List<SmsResponse> smsResponseList)
    {
        bool isSent = smsResponseList.Exists(response => response.Response != 0);
        if (!isSent)
            PrepareStatusString(smsResponseList);
        return isSent;
    }

     private void PrepareStatusString(List<SmsResponse> responseList)
    {
        bool isfirst = true;
        foreach (var item in responseList)
        {
            if (item.Response != 0)
            {
                if(isfirst)
                    StatusDescription += item.AliasName + "|" + item.CellPhoneNumber + "|" + item.Response.ToString();
                else
                    StatusDescription += "," + item.AliasName + "|" + item.CellPhoneNumber + "|" + item.Response.ToString();

                isfirst = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

The code is working as desired, but can it be optimized/improved in any way. I am feeling there is a scope improvement but not able to figure out ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using .NET 4 or newer, you can override `SmsResponse.ToString()` and then use [`String.Join<T>(String, IEnumerable<T>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx) to concatenate the responses.

So your `SmsResponse` class may look something like this:

```
public class SmsResponse
{
    public string AliasName { get; set; }
    public string CellPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public int Response { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return AliasName + "|" + CellPhoneNumber + "|" +
            Response.ToString();
    }
}
```

And `PrepareStatusString` would be:

```
private void PrepareStatusString(List<SmsResponse> responseList)
{
    StatusDescription = string.Join(",", responseList.Where(i => i.Response != 0));
}
```

Comment: i am using .net framework 4.0 and like the solution too, but it is giving me an error in string key word of the function public override string ToString() stating "expected class,delegate,enum,interface or struct"

Comment: @ankur It seems you've copied the `ToString()` method into a namespace scope instead of a class scope.

Comment: there is a small issue with this , i don't want to add the whole list StatusDescription = string.Join(",", responseList);,Insted I only want to add those item whose response are not 0. Can we add this check in any way

Comment: @ankur Yes, you can filter out those responses using LINQ ([Enumerable.Where<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, Boolean>)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx)). I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 4):

`StringBuilder` will be more efficient at appending strings within the foreach loop (depending on num of iterations)

```
private void PrepareStatusString(List<SmsResponse> responseList)
{
    bool isfirst = true;
    StringBulder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var item in responseList)
    {
        if (item.Response != 0)
        {
            if(isfirst)
                sb.AppendFormat("{0}|{1}|{2}", item.AliasName, item.CellPhoneNumber,item.Response.ToString());
            else
                sb.AppendFormat(",{0}|{1}|{2}", item.AliasName, item.CellPhoneNumber, item.Response.ToString());

            isfirst = false;
        }
    }

    StatusDescription = sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about optimization, but it could be rewritten more expressively as follows:

```
private void PrepareStatusString(List<SmsResponse> responseList)
{
    StatusDescription = responseList
         .Where(x => x.Response != 0)
         .Select(x => x.AliasName 
                    + "|" + x.CellPhoneNumber 
                    + "|" + x.Response.ToString())
         .Aggregate((x, y) => x + "," + y);
}
```

Note that `StringBuilder` will only offer a noticeable performance benefit if you expect more than a couple hundred objects there.

Comment: it is giving error in item as it does not exist in current context. are you intending in using this LINQ statement inside the loop...

Comment: It should work now. Yes, my intention was to use the current context.

Answer (score 0):

Use `string.Join` like so

```
    List<string> elements = new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in responseList)
    {
        if (item.Response != 0)
        {
            elements.add(item.AliasName + "|" + item.CellPhoneNumber + "|" + item.Response.ToString());
        }
    }
    string result = string.Join(",", elements.ToArray());
```